# Restricting user access to nvidia GPU?

Tags: linux, drivers, nvidia, gpu, cuda

On a server with Tesla Nvidia Card we decide to Restrict user access to GPU. In our server 2 GPU.

```
# ls -las /dev/nvidia*
0 crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 195,   0 Dec  2 22:02 /dev/nvidia0
0 crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 195,   1 Dec  2 22:02 /dev/nvidia1
```

I found this solve [Defining User Restrictions for GPUs](https://towardsdatascience.com/defining-user-restrictions-for-gpus-6971a658a9ce)

I create local group gpu_cuda

```
sudo groupadd gpu_cuda
```

after add user to group **gpu_cuda**

Create a config file at /etc/modprob.d/nvidia.conf with content

```
#!/bin/bash
options nvidia NVreg_DeviceFileUID=0 NVreg_DeviceFileGID=0 NVreg_DeviceFileMode=0777 NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles=0
```

Create script in /etc/init.d/gpu-restriction

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          gpu-restriction
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
#  permissions if needed.
### END INIT INFO
set -e
start() {
/sbin/modprobe --ignore-install nvidia;
/sbin/modprobe nvidia_uvm;
test -c /dev/nvidia-uvm || mknod -m 777 /dev/nvidia-uvm c $(cat /proc/devices | while read major device; do if [ "$device" == "nvidia-uvm" ]; then echo $major; break; fi ; done) 0 && chown :root /dev/nvidia-uvm; 
test -c /dev/nvidiactl || mknod -m 777 /dev/nvidiactl c 195 255 && chown :root /dev/nvidiactl; 
devid=-1; 
for dev in $(ls -d /sys/bus/pci/devices/*); 
do vendorid=$(cat $dev/vendor); 
if [ "$vendorid" == "0x10de" ]; 
then class=$(cat $dev/class); 
classid=${class%%00}; 
if [ "$classid" == "0x0300" -o "$classid" == "0x0302" ]; 
then devid=$((devid+1)); 
test -c /dev/nvidia${devid} || mknod -m 750 /dev/nvidia${devid} c 195 ${devid} && chown :gpu_cuda /dev/nvidia${devid}; 
fi; 
fi; 
done
}
stop() {
:
}
case "$1" in
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       # code to check status of app comes here 
       # example: status program_name
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac
exit 0
```

I reboot server and run

```
/etc/init.d/gpu-restriction start
```

check result in first time is good.

```
# ls -las /dev/nvidia*
0 crw-rw-rw-. 1 root gpu_cuda 195,   0 Dec  2 22:02 /dev/nvidia0
0 crw-rw-rw-. 1 root gpu_cuda 195,   1 Dec  2 22:02 /dev/nvidia1
```

but in second time, chown group is back to root

```
# ls -las /dev/nvidia*
0 crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 195,   0 Dec  2 22:02 /dev/nvidia0
0 crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 195,   1 Dec  2 22:02 /dev/nvidia1
```

Why result back? and how to solve this problem?

Comment: 1/ /etc/modprob.d/nvidia.conf ? missing e . Typo error I presume ? 2/ NVreg_DeviceFileGID=0 ? Why do you keep that to root GID ?

Comment: added to post URL Defining User Restrictions for GPUs https://towardsdatascience.com/defining-user-restrictions-for-gpus-6971a658a9ce , config from this article used

Comment: Hmmmm… had a hardtime understanding what the guy is doing. But… as a starting point, for sure, there is indeed a typo error in this page : you should definitely read **/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf** modprob**e**.d directory in which you should already get some nvidia.conf. I'll try to figure out the rest of the mess…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvidia provides the way to set the group ID of its special device files without needing to resort to whatever extra somber script :

> Whether a user-space NVIDIA driver component does so itself, or
> invokes nvidia-modprobe, it will default to creating the device files
> with the following attributes:
>
> ```
>   UID:  0     - 'root'
>   GID:  0     - 'root'
>   Mode: 0666  - 'rw-rw-rw-'
> ```
>
> Existing device files are changed if their attributes don't match these defaults.
> If you want the NVIDIAdriver to create the device files with different attributes, you can
> specify them with the "NVreg_DeviceFileUID" (user),
> "NVreg_DeviceFileGID" (group) and "NVreg_DeviceFileMode" NVIDIA Linux
> kernel module parameters.

The nvidia Linux kernel modue parameters can be set in the /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf file, mine tells :

```
...
options nvidia \
        NVreg_DeviceFileGID=27 \
        NVreg_DeviceFileMode=432 \
        NVreg_DeviceFileUID=0 \
        NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles=1\
...
```

And I indeed can `ls -ails /dev/nvidia0` :

```
3419 0 crw-rw---- 1 root video 195, 0  4 déc.  15:01 /dev/nvidia0
```

and witness the fact that access to root owned special files is actually restricted to the members of the video group (GID=27 on my system)

Therefore, all you need to do is to get the group id of your `gpu_cuda` group and modify (or setup) your nvidia.conf accordingly.

---

Credits : `/usr/share/doc/nvidia-drivers-470.141.03/html/faq.html` (you'll probably need to adapt the path to your driver version).

Comment: in my os group gpu_cuda - 1226: options nvidia \
        NVreg_DeviceFileGID=1226 \
        NVreg_DeviceFileMode=432 \
        NVreg_DeviceFileUID=0 \
        NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles=1 ok?

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko : Precisely! (Please mark this answer accepted if that fits your needs. (in order for other members of the community not to waste time investigating the useless script posted in OP)

Comment: sure I mark, but this variant not working, may be this important # nvidia-smi
Mon Dec  5 12:59:38 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.27.04    Driver Version: 460.27.04    CUDA Version: 11.2     |

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko : Please post the output of your /etc/modeprobe.d/nvidia.conf

Comment: Are you sure /etc/modEprobe.d/nvidia.conf? # cat /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf
#!/bin/bash
options nvidia \
        NVreg_DeviceFileGID=1226 \
        NVreg_DeviceFileMode=0660 \
        NVreg_DeviceFileUID=0 \
        NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles=1

Comment: on host exist only this files: # nvidia
nvidia-bug-report.sh     nvidia-cuda-mps-control  nvidia-cuda-mps-server   nvidia-debugdump         nvidia-modprobe          nvidia-persistenced      nvidia-smi               nvidia-xconfig
nvidia - absent.

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko : Yes ! My bad sorry ! modprobe.d . I managed to find the nvidia page relevent to your driver version :  https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/460.27.04/README/faq.html leading to the question : What init system is your system running (systemd ? openrc ? other ?) How did you install your drivers ? (installing distro dedicated package ? other ?) In fine how are your nvidia modules loaded ?

Comment: I check installed RPMs # yum search nvidia-modprobe nvidia-modprobe-branch-460.x86_64 : NVIDIA kernel module loader
nvidia-modprobe-latest.x86_64 : NVIDIA kernel module loader
nvidia-modprobe-latest-dkms.x86_64 : NVIDIA kernel module loader